# create threads in python in setDaemon mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS` with python-2.7.12. I'm not an expert in `python`, but I have to maintain some code. Here is snippet:

```
from threading import Thread
...

class Shell(cmd.Cmd):
    ...
    def do_start(self, line):
        threads = []

        t = Thread(target=traffic(line, arg1, arg2, arg3)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        t.join()
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global config
    global args

    args = parse_args()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(args.FILE)

    s = Shell()
    ...
```

So it starts a small command-line shell, where I can execute some commands. It does work, however it blocks the CLI, as the threads starts, so I googled and thought that adding `t.setDaemon(True)` would help. I tried it before `t.start()` or after, and it didn't take any effect. Is it not supported in this version, or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `t.join()` makes the main thread to wait for the one created, so the CLI is blocked.

If you want to run your CLI and not block the terminal you need to run it in the background.
If you run on Linux you can simply use the `&` sign

Comment: But I need access to python CLI.

Comment: I am not sure what use case you want to achieve, but if you want to run multiple commands from your CLI you can do something like:
`python my_cli command_1 &`
`python my_cli command_2 &`

This way you can run commands using your CLI in the background. Note that your code must be multi-process safe.